# GCP service account naming

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts

I'm setting up GCP, and one of the things I'd like to utilize is the Secrets Manager. In order to rotate keys, you need to set up pub/sub, and that needs a service account with the proper roles. I'm being asked to create a service account ending with `@gcp-sa-secretmanager.iam.gserviceaccount.com`. I can only seem to add SAs that end with `@my-project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com`.

I can't find anything in the docs... anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally these accounts are Google-managed Service Accounts.

You do **not** create them yourself but you can reference them including binding them to IAM policies. See [Service Agents](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-agents)

You didn't include a reference (!) but I assume you're using this [Event Notifications for Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/event-notifications)

When you [create a service agent identity](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/event-notifications#service-identity) a Service Account of the form you describe (`service-PROJECT_NUMBER@gcp-sa-secretmanager.iam.gserviceaccount.com`) is **returned** (a reference to a Google-managed Service Account) by the command for you to use.

Comment: Ahhhh, I was trying to set it up via the UI. `gcloud` it is!